# Find the limit and justify convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Find the limit and justify convergence. $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\int_{0}^{n}{\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)}}^n\log{\left(2+\cos{(x/n)}\right)}dx $$

Consider \begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)}^n\log{\left(2+\cos{(x/n)}\right) }dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty}{ e^{-x}\cdot \log(3) dx} \\
   &= \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty }{ \int_{0}^{b} { e^{-x}\cdot \log(3) dx } } \\
   &= \log(3) \cdot \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty }{ 1 - e^{-b} } \\
   &= \log(3)
    \end{align*}

I don't think I am able to use Monotone Convergence Theorem here because the function has negative values for small n. I have tried Dominant Convergence theorem, but I can't find the appropriate function that will be greater than or equal to the absolute value of the integrand.

Comment: No, the $n$th integrand is nonnegative on $[0,n]$ for all $n.$ See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways to do this:

1. Monotone convergence theorem. It's a bit tricky, but it will work.
2. Dominated convergence theorem. This is the easiest way. Here take $f_n(x) = \chi_{[0,n]}(x) (1-x/n)^n \ln (2 + \cos(x/n)).$ A dominating function is $e^{-x}\ln 3,$ but you need to verify this.
3. You may not have seen this result, but I'll mention it anyway: If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1],$ then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int_0^1 (1-y)^n f(y)\,dy = f(0).$$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$To apply this, let $x=ny$ in the given integral.